# How to click an element that we get from http request using SetInterval?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
 window.addEventListener("load" , () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "./messagedUsers.php", true);
        xhttp.onload = () => {
            if(xhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if(xhttp.status === 200) {
                    let data = xhttp.response;
                    sideActiveUsers.innerHTML = data;
                }
            }
        }
        xhttp.send();
    } , 500);
    messageInputContainer.focus();
})
let userInfo = document.querySelectorAll(".user-info");
userInfoClick(userInfo); // function that does operation using the nodeList userInfo
```

In the above code , what I'm trying to do is send a HttpRequest to the php and get a div container as a response from there. As a response , I do get the div container. The div I got from there has a class name "user-info". And I want to click it and further , apply some css to the all the elements it holds(as there will be lot of "user-info" container coming from the response.). What I'm unable to figure out is "user-info" container can be applied styling through css(not JS). But if I try to use some JS for the node with className "user-info" , nothing happens as the nodeList seems to be empty.

And I've also tried using querySelector inside the setInterval for "user-info". But that makes the function outside userInfoClick(userInfo) takes a userInfo that is not defined.

And if I use both querySelector and the function that takes the variable that holds that nodeList(userInfoClick), I am able to click the element coming back from php. But its effect is stopped after every 500 ms(as the setInterval is set for 500ms).

I want to be able to click the element coming back from php and click it whose effect doesn't change after every 500ms(along with the element getting from php every 500ms).

Help me out guys.

userInfoClick function:

```
const userInfoClick = (userInfo) => {
    let userinfo = Array.from(userInfo);
    userinfo.forEach((el , ind) => {
        el.addEventListener("click" , () => {
            for(let i=0 ; i<userInfo.length ; i++)
                {
                    if(ind!==i)
                        {
                            userinfo[i].style.backgroundColor = "#dddddd";
                        }
                }
            el.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
        })
    })   
}
```

Comment: Can you show your userInfoClick function?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Kinglish. I have added the userIInfoClick function above.

Comment: It looks like you're calling `let userInfo = document.querySelectorAll(".user-info"); userInfoClick(userInfo);` in the wrong place. It should be in the `setInterval()` function, immediately after `sideActiveUsers.innerHTML = data;`, when the DOM has been populated.

Comment: Thanks @kmoser for the response. Yes I've tried that one. As I have mentioned above when I set userInfo and call the function userInfoClick inside the setInterval() , the process seems to reiterate every 500 ms(that's what setInterval is meant to do actually) , the click gets triggered but once again stops after 500 ms. But ,  I want to get both the query and the click action on it without stopping of the click action.

Comment: _" I want to get both the query and the click action on it without stopping of the click action."_ This doesn't make sense. Please clarify.

Comment: The use of userInfoClick function is to take a nodeList and whenever we click on any node inside it , it changes the background color. If I use the  querySelectorAll to get the nodeList and userInfoClick inside setInterval() function , the querySelection and the function call reruns every 500 ms. And If I click on the userInfo node which is coming from php every 500 ms , the click i just did disappears every 500 ms. so if i try to access "user-info" class , it's not possible outside the setInterval() and if i access it inside the setInterval() , the click action disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind an event handler to an element that does not yet exist. The `querySelectorAll` call will return an empty collection, as the assignment to `innerHTML` will only happen in some future.

In this case, where you have the interval, it is better to use *event delegation*. This means that you listen to click events at a higher level in the DOM tree -- on an element that is always there and is not dynamically created. In your case this could be `sideActiveUsers`.

So change your code as follows:

Remove this line (as it will return a useless empty collection):

```
let userInfo = document.querySelectorAll(".user-info");
```

And change the `userInfoClick` function, which should be called only once, without any arguments:

```
function userInfoClick() {
    sideActiveUsers.addEventListener("click" , (e) => {
        const el = e.target;
        // We're only interested in user-info clicks:
        if (!el.classList.contains("user-info")) return;
        // Since we clicked on a user-info, the following will now have matches:
        for (const sibling of sideActiveUsers.querySelectorAll(".user-info")) {
            sibling.style.backgroundColor = "#dddddd";
        }
        el.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    });
}
```

Comment: Even with the use of Event Delegation , the action lasted just for fraction of seconds. As you said I have used the userInfoClick() function just once without any arguments. The response from php seems to disturb the action.

Comment: Which action do you refer to? Yes, adding the event listener is instantaneous. I don't know what you mean with "action" when you say it is "disturbed". Can you please describe this in technical terms?

Comment: By saying action , I'm referring to the click action on the sideActiveUsers. It only gets clicked for just fraction of seconds(showed by the disappearance of the background color).

Comment: disappearance of background color? You mean #dddddd or #fff? Did you put some debug code to see which lines are executed? BTW: it is expected to run only a fraction of a second. There is nothing long running in that code.

Comment: I mean shouldn't the effect(change in background color)be seen after click for much more time. It just changes the background color for fraction of seconds. Is it beacause of the response(the userInfo) we get every 500ms from the php through http request?

Comment: Yes, indeed the assignment to `innerHTML` will overwrite whatever style you have applied. If you want that differently, then apply the same logic just after the assignment to `innerHTML`. But you'll need to remember what was the last item that was clicked, ...etc. If you cannot make that work, then that deserves a new question.